# Extract Two Sets of Data With One SQL Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to be able to extract two sets of data in one script with a total of 15 records.

In my scenario, I extract members from a certain town which for example could return 3 records, and then I want to extract the remaining 12 from that particular state.

Here is a coding sample:

```
SELECT MemberID, a.UserName, a.MemberDisplayName, a.NYKABizName, a.PackageType
FROM Member a
WHERE a.Claimed = 'Y'
AND a.PrCity = 'Bridgewater'
AND a.PrStateID = 36
AND a.PackageType = 'E'
ORDER BY a.MemberDisplayName

SELECT MemberID, a.UserName, a.MemberDisplayName, a.NYKABizName, a.PackageType
FROM Member a
WHERE a.Claimed = 'Y'
AND a.PrStateID = 36
AND a.PackageType = 'E'
ORDER BY a.MemberDisplayName
```

I dont want these two combined into one, I want a temporary virtual table where the results are stored and then the virtual table is returned once complete.

Any ideas how one can accomplish this?

Many thanks in advance,
neojakey

Comment: You mean you want two data sets returned from a single procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [virtual table](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) would look like this

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
    SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT MemberID, a.UserName, a.MemberDisplayName, a.NYKABizName, a.PackageType
    FROM Member a
    WHERE a.Claimed = 'Y'
    AND a.PrCity = 'Bridgewater'
    AND a.PrStateID = 36
    AND a.PackageType = 'E'
    ORDER BY a.MemberDisplayName
    ) x 
    UNION 
    (
    SELECT MemberID, a.UserName, a.MemberDisplayName, a.NYKABizName, a.PackageType
    FROM Member a
    WHERE a.Claimed = 'Y'
    AND a.PrStateID = 36
    AND a.PackageType = 'E'
    ORDER BY a.MemberDisplayName
    ) y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple select statements in data adapter separated by “;”.

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(“select * from table1;select * from table2”, connection);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

Then you can reference the result sets with ds.Tables[index].

[C# DataAdapter and DataSet with multiple table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574606/c-sharp-dataadapter-and-dataset-with-multiple-table)