# How to pass 2 datatable from dataset in crystal report using 2 sql queries?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

i have a dataset with 2 datatable aand I need to use 2 sql request to display data in crystal report. So i create 2 datatable in my dataset (DataTable1 and dataTable2) I tried this code but it always execute the second sql request!!

```
 con.ConnectionString = @"connection";

            string sql = "MyRequest1";
            string sql1 = "MyRequest2";

            DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();  

            SqlDataAdapter dad = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            SqlDataAdapter dad1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, con);

            dad.Fill(ds.Tables["DataTable1"]);
            dad1.Fill(ds.Tables["DataTable2"]);

            CrystalReport1 report = new CrystalReport1();

            report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["DataTable2"]);
            report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["DataTable1"]);

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;

            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Have u checked whether data is getting fetched by the first sql, if not run in debug mode & check the ds.Tables["DataTable1"]. Also u can check the sql in ur db

Comment: i have maked some modification to the code. now it execute  only the first request and display right values but it doesn't execute the second request !!

Comment: This is a common mistake done. Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574606/c-sharp-dataadapter-and-dataset-with-multiple-table]

Comment: thanks for your reply but in my situation I have to use 2 sql request!!

Comment: try this & replace them with ur requirements, `SqlDataAdapter custAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
  "SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers", customerConnection);
OleDbDataAdapter ordAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(
  "SELECT * FROM Orders", orderConnection);

DataSet customerOrders = new DataSet();

custAdapter.Fill(customerOrders, "Customers");
ordAdapter.Fill(customerOrders, "Orders");

DataRelation relation = customerOrders.Relations.Add("CustOrders",
  customerOrders.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustomerID"],
  customerOrders.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustomerID"]);`